# Reference type in java and pointers in C difference

Tags: java, c, pointers, reference

I am trying to understand the difference between reference type in java and pointers in C.

I wrote the following two programs in C and Java.

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *p;
    int *q;

    int a = 5;

    p = &a;

    q = p;

    printf("before q: %p\n",q);

    p = NULL;

    printf("before p: %p\n",q);

    return 0;
}
```

Here p & q, both points to the same location. Now any effect in p doesn't affect q.

Java:

```
class BoxDemo
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int length;
}


class Box {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BoxDemo b1 = new BoxDemo();
        BoxDemo b2 = b1;


        System.out.println("after: b2: " + b2);
        b1 = null;
        System.out.println("before: b2:  " + b2);


    }
}
```

Here b1 and b2 points at the same location. But, changes made in b1 doesn't reflect in b2.

So, what is the difference between these two types, reference and pointers? Are both the same?

Comment: You nulled the `b1` reference, you didn't make any changes to the value `b1` references.

Comment: So, shouldn't the value of b2 be null also?

Comment: your c and java code are not same. where are you setting the pointer to null in your c code?

Comment: In your Java code, you make `b1` and `b2` refer to the same object, then you set `b1` to `null`.  Why do you expect reassigning one variable to change what the other one references?

Answer (score 0):

You `null` the reference, not the value. Consider something like

```
class BoxDemo {
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int length;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%d x %d x %d", width, height, length);
    }
}
```

Then modify `b1.width` after assigning the reference to `b2`. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BoxDemo b1 = new BoxDemo();
    b1.width = b1.height = b1.length = 100;
    BoxDemo b2 = b1;
    b1.width = 2;
    System.out.println(b2);
}
```

Output is

```
2 x 100 x 100
```

Because `b2` refers to the same `BoxDemo` instance as `b1`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please have a look on the edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
*p = 10;
```

means change the value inside the address that p points at to 10
and since p and q both point to the same address, they both see the value inside this address equals 10 .... this is equivalent to :

```
BoxDemo b1 = new BoxDemo();
BoxDemo b2 = b1;
b1.someIntegerParameterInside = 10;
System.out.print(b2.someIntegerParameterInside); //will print 10
```

while

```
b1 = null;
```

means, change the ***object*** (***address***) that b1 is pointing to to another address, equivalent to

```
p = &v;
```

where v is another int variable.